# Linear inequality plot with shading

Tags: gnuplot

I simply want to show a linear equation `-2x + 7 >= y` with one side of the line shaded. I've tried various `filledcurve` iterations to no avail. Something so simple shouldn't be this difficult methinks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your (non-working) code.

Comment: Problem solved? Any response would be appreciated...

Comment: I guess I'm just struck, discouraged by yet another supposedly "ancillary" part of the STEM puzzle, i.e., graphs and diagrams, that nonetheless wants to take over my life. Yet another steep learning curve. Suffering from a reality bite here. Alas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do a reasonable search before you ask and provide your (non-working) code. Have you checked `help filledcurves`? What exactly is not clear there?
Check the example below:

**Code:**

```
### fill area below or above curve
reset session

set grid x,y front
set style fill solid 0.3

f(x) = -2*x+7

plot f(x) w filledcurves x1 lc "red", \
     f(x) w filledcurves x2 lc "green", \
     f(x) w l

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]